# How to change $InitialDirectory?

Tags: files-and-directories

I want to launch Mathematica in `$HomeDirectory/mywork/mathematica`, not `$HomeDirectory`.
But, `$InitialDirectory` is locked and protected.
Is there any way to change `$InitialDirectory`?

Comment: Is `SetDirectory @ whatever` ok or is there any real reason to change `$InitialDirectory`?

Comment: I know that, but it is very bothering to type SetDirectory every time.

Comment: You can add this to `ini.m`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added `SetDirectory` to `~/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m`.

Comment: great, I linked it to the old question, which has the same answer, as a road sign. Good luck.